# How to override the equals method of a subclass

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, overriding, equals

I am trying to sync users between two different locations, therefore I keep existing users in a list, and hence do a comparison at a set time interval to see if the user should be added (new) or just updated.

I have a class User that is the subclass to Principal.

However my **compare** on the list does not work; I googled a bit and found that you have to override the equals method, and I do - but that code does not seem to be executed, it goes into ArrayList.class (primitive) and executes the contains method there.

Is this because my class already extends the superclass Principal?
What are my options if I want to execute the equals that I defined in User class?

```
public class User extends Principal
{
    // some protected properties
    ...

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return (this.getAlias().equals(((User) obj).getAlias())
                && this.getEmailAddress().equals(((User) obj).getEmailAddress()) && this.getCellNumber().equals(((User) obj).getCellNumber()));
    } 
}
```

The Principal class does not override the equals method, and more importantly, the properties I check for equality, is only contained in the subclass - User. Therefore it makes sense to check it here.

So in short, I have an ArrayList of Users, and I would like to check whether a certain User already exists or not. I call compare on the list, but it always fails, indicative that the method equals is not overrided properly in my code. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What you are doing is good.

Comment: I'm assuming your `ArrayList` contains `Principal` objects?

Comment: Please add the code where you actually compare things in the list.

Comment: 1. It sounds like this is supposed to be thread safe. 2. For performance reasons might be better to use a better data structure to hold your users, for faster retrieval and update. For example a Map. You only need to create a key for your user and the pain will go away. Or better a concurrent one - `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: The ArrayList is of type User, not Principal.

Answer (score 3):

You should not implement `equals()` (and `hashcode()`) in a super class.

The reason is that when `equals()` returns **true** `hashcode()` **must return *same* value**

Imagine you have class `Point2D` and class `Point3D` extending the other.

Shall a *point2D* be equal to a *point3D* with same area coordinates? 
If so then *point3D* must return the same hashcode as the "equal" *point2D* and that means that you cannot not store more that one *poin3d* with same area coordinates in a Hash bases collection (eg.: as keys in a HashMap).

Answer (score 2):

Overriding equals is not as evident as it looks

- equals with null must return false
- equals with an object of a different class must return false because of symetry a.equals(b) <=> b.equals(a)

java

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass()!=getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    return Object.equals(this.getAlias(),((User) obj).getAlias())
        && Object.equals(this.getEmailAddress(),((User) obj).getEmailAddress())
        && Object.equals(this.getCellNumber(),((User) obj).getCellNumber()));
}
```

Also if object is used in hash collections it must override hashCode so that two objects that are equals must return the same hashCode, the contrary is not true.

Comment: I am trying this option out - one cannot return null when the return type expected is a boolean...

Comment: the code was given as an example but it was fixed: changed return null by return false

Comment: Important to note, if you're overriding the `equals()` then `hashcode()` should be overriden as well to prevent unexpected behavior with `Collection`s

Comment: @CraigR8806, I agree specially for hash containers, but from the question it's ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from you instantiating a `List<Person>`. The compiler can't know if every subclasses of Person override `equals`. To correct this, you should **promise** your compiler you'll override this method, which you can do by changing your `Person` class to an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Person {
    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object o);
}

public class User extends Person {
    // Some stuff...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || ! (o instanceof User))
            return false;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: The hashCode is used only with hash containers HashSet HashMap... but in this case it's an ArrayList

Comment: My comment comes from the specs of hashCodes and equals, if the equals method returns true, the hashcode returns true. This **must** be always respected, so it's better to override both.

Answer (score 0):

According to the book Effective Java.If you have override the equals method,then you must override the hashcode method.
some advice when you override the equals method:
 1. equals with null return false.
 2. !(obj instanceof this) return false.
 3. cast obj to this class and compare the parameters in the obj and this class.
return the result in the end

Answer (score -1):

You should use the contains methode of the arrayList

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: That won't work if he doesn't override his equals and hashCode. The contains method uses these functions to check if the element is already in the list.